# Which web site can I use for setting ns1, ns2 for a parent domain name?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, reseller

I bought a domain from reseller like below :

`www.test.com`

I want to use this domain as my parent domain.

This domain in the reseller's web site has a control panel that I should set `ns1.something.com` and `ns2.something.com` but in those text boxes we can not put any ip-address!

What are these `ns1.something.com` and `ns2.something.com`?

I have a server with a valid IP address.

How can I connect that domain to this IP valid of my server (should I do this job in my server or other place - I mean which web site and panel should I use to do that)?

Comment: To be honest, given that you show complete lack of knowledge about basic DNS terms, you should really consider using a hosted service and not buolding it yourself. DNS requires some knowledge and if you mess that up, *bad things will happen*™. This is the most basic infrastructure on which everything else relies on for your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain reseller should have a control panel that provides you with the option to amend the DNS records for this domain.  In that panel you should be able to end an A record to point  the `www.test.com` to your server's IP address.

The `ns1.something.com` & `ns2.something.com` specify which DNS servers should be used to look up records under the `test.com` domain. By default these would be set to use your resellers name servers which their control panel would be updating but you can switch to it use another DNS service if you wish or point them to your own DNS server as well if required.

Comment: thanks for answer / i want to use my own server as dns server / mean how can i create ns1.test.com and ns2.test.com and use these name servers for mother domain (www.test.com) and the other domains from that reseller?

Comment: ask your reseller...

Comment: they told me can do that for 6$ / but i think it should be for free

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a valid public zone for your domain **first**.

For now, I may suggest you to use a [authoritative DNS server](http://www.google.de/search?q=free+nameserver).

Comment: thanks for answer / would you plz explain more ! / my server -> server 2008 r2 - both dns and iis have been installed ...

Comment: what is valid public zone?

Comment: you need a public zone, that will share dns-informations globally (eg. your mx-records). Try out [http://www.zoneedit.com](http://www.zoneedit.com). Create a new zone for your domain and add the nameservers provided by **ZoneEdit** to your domain-configuration.